# Check a multiple in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am trying to find the odd numbers and a multiple of 7 between a 1 to 100 and append them into an array. I have got this far:

```
var results: [Int] = []
for n in 1...100 {
    if n / 2 != 0 && 7 / 100 == 0 {
        results.append(n)
    }
}
```

Comment: `n / 2 != 0` holds true for all integers bigger than 1, not just the odd ones.

Comment: Swift 5.0 gives .isMultiple(of: 2)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your conditions are incorrect. You want to use "[modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)"

Odd numbers are *not divisible by 2*. To check this use:

```
if n % 2 != 0
```

The `%` is the mod function and it returns the *remainder* of the division (e.g. `5 / 2` is 2.5 but integers don't have decimals, so the integer result is 2 with a remainder of 1 and `5 / 2 => 2` and `5 % 2 => 1`)

To check if it's divisible by 7, use the same principle:

```
if n % 7 == 0
```

The remainder is 0 if the dividend is divisible by the divisor. The complete `if` condition is:

```
if n % 2 != 0 && n % 7 == 0
```

You can also use `n % 2 == 1` because the remainder is always 1. The result of any mod function, `a % b`, is always between `0` and `b - 1`.

Or, using the new function `isMultiple(of:`, that final condition would be:

```
if !n.isMultiple(of: 2) && n.isMultiple(of: 7)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.

Answer (score 8):

### Swift 5:

Since Swift 5 has been released, you could use [`isMultiple(of:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0225-binaryinteger-iseven-isodd-ismultiple.md) method.

In your case, you should check if it is not multiple of ... :

```
if !n.isMultiple(of: 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5** is coming with `isMultiple(of:)` method for integers , so you can try

```
let res = Array(1...100).filter { !$0.isMultiple(of:2) && $0.isMultiple(of:7) }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an efficient and concise way of getting the odd multiples of 7 less than or equal to 100 :

```
let results: [Int] = Array(stride(from: 7, through: 100, by: 14))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the built-in filter to do an operation on only qualified members of an array. Here is how that'd go in your case for example

```
var result = Array(1...100).filter { (number) -> Bool in
    return (number % 2 != 0 && number % 7 == 0)
}
print(result) // will print [7, 21, 35, 49, 63, 77, 91]
```

You can read more about filter in the doc but here is the basics: it goes through each element and collects elements that return true on the condition. So it filters the array and returns what you want